# Linux driver installation on ARM chromebook gives architecture error

Tags: drivers, software-installation, google-chrome, chromebook

So basically I bought an Artist 12 2nd gen tablet and I only have a chrome laptop so currently I need to install the Linux driver to use it and properly draw.

It constantly says "Error while installing package: package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)" when I try to install it and I am literally lost.

Comment: Can you explain some more details about what you're doing? What commands you're running, what your environment is and so forth?

Answer (score 1):

Find a download that says `arm64`. A download for `amd64` is not compatible with a system that needs `arm64`.

- [arm desktop installer](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/)  The one that states

> Desktop image for 64-bit ARM (ARMv8/AArch64) computers (standard download)

- [Server versions arm64](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm)